# Java Swing not showing components as it should

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to code the GUI for a class in Java and some components appear but some don't. Precisely JTextBoxes and JButton appear but JLabels and JComboBoxes don't. Another problem is that I tried to remove the JComboBox and put JTextBox, but when I tried to type a blood type (es. O-) and register it in the object Donor d1, it gave me NumberFormatException. I checked Donor class and the attribute bloodType is a String so I don't see why would it give me this error

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class DonationForm {
    DonorTableImpl donorDB;

    public DonationForm(DonorTableImpl donorDB){
        this.donorDB=donorDB;
        JFrame formFrame=new JFrame("Complete the form");

        //TextBox Fields
        JTextField id=new JTextField(10);
        id.setBounds(140,190,150,30);
        JTextField firstName=new JTextField(10);
        firstName.setBounds(140,160,150,30);
        JTextField lastName=new JTextField(10);
        lastName.setBounds(140,130,150,30);
        JTextField password=new JTextField(10);
        password.setBounds(140,100,150,30);
        JTextField address=new JTextField(10);
        address.setBounds(140,70,150,30);
        
        //Labels for TextBoxes
        JLabel idLabel=new JLabel("Id");
        JLabel firstNameLabel=new JLabel("First Name");
        JLabel lastNameLabel=new JLabel("Last Name");
        JLabel passwordLabel=new JLabel("Password");
        JLabel addressLabel=new JLabel("Address");
        JLabel bloodTypeLabel=new JLabel("Blood Type");

        //ComboBox
        String[] blood={"A+","A-","B+","B-","AB+","AB-","O+","O-"};
        JComboBox bloodType=new JComboBox(blood);
        bloodType.setSelectedIndex(0);

        //Submit button
        JButton submit=new JButton("SUBMIT");
        submit.setBounds(190,300,100,30);

        //Add all components on frame
        formFrame.add(idLabel);
        formFrame.add(id);
        formFrame.add(firstNameLabel);
        formFrame.add(firstName);
        formFrame.add(lastNameLabel);
        formFrame.add(lastName);
        formFrame.add(passwordLabel);
        formFrame.add(password);
        formFrame.add(addressLabel);
        formFrame.add(address);
        formFrame.add(bloodTypeLabel);
        formFrame.add(bloodType);
        formFrame.add(submit);
        formFrame.setSize(500,500);
        bloodType.setVisible(true);
        bloodType.setLayout(null);
        formFrame.setLayout(null);
        formFrame.setVisible(true);

        //Create an Object with data gotten from TextBoxes when SUBMIT button is clicked
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Donor d1=new Donor(Integer.parseInt(id.getText()),firstName.getText(),
                        lastName.getText(),password.getText(),
                        address.getText(), blood[bloodType.getSelectedIndex()]);
                donorDB.save(d1);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: **Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds()**. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `formFrame.setLayout(null);`
you chose to not use a [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) for your `JFrame`.
This is usually a bad idea, because then you are responsible
for setting the positions and sizes of the components.
You did this by calling `.setBounds(x,y,width,height)` for some
of your components (the `JTextField`s and the `JButton`),
But you didn't do this for some other components (the `JLabel`s
and the `JComboBox`). That's why these components
still have position/size zero and hence are invisible.

Now I don't suggest you add these missing `.setBounds(...)` calls,
because this would lead to an even messier design.

Instead do the following:

- Avoid `formFrame.setLayout(null)`  on your `JFrame`.
  Instead use `formFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5))`.
  This will arrange the components in a grid-like manner
  with 2 columns (in the sequence you added them to the frame),
  separated by 5-pixel gaps between the rows and columns.
- Remove all the `.setBounds(...)` calls.
  You don't need them, because this is what a layout manager
  can do better.
- Avoid `bloodType.setLayout(null)` on your `JComboBox`,
  because this would make the drop-down button of the combobox
  invisible.
- Avoid `formFrame.setSize(500,500)`.
  Instead use `formFrame.pack()`. This will cause the layout
  manager to give calculated positions and sizes to your components.
  (That's why you need to do this *after* the `.setLayout(...)` call).

Then it will look like this.

[image]

I recommend to learn more about how to layout components in Swing.
See for example [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).
With the skills from there you may even want to further improve
the appearance of your `JFrame`.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me a small window, however when I change it's size it looks good. I tried maintaining the formFrame.setSize() in order to fix windows size and changed GridLayout hgap and vgap in order to have smaller components. It looks better but I would like to have the two colons or let's say Labels and TextFields closer. Also the SUBMIT button on the right side. I tried changing GridLayout values but can't get it to work. How do I do this?

Comment: @Steve (1) For a better layout you might need another more advanced layout manager instead of GridLayout (see the linked tutorial). GridLayout is designed to give the same size to all components.  
(2) For putting the SUBMIT button into the right column you can add an invisible dummy component just before it:
`formFrame.add(new Box(0))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the frame's layout to something besides null in order to render all components.

Instead of

```
formFrame.setLayout(null);
```

Use this:

```
formFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 1000, 10));
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it shows all the components except of ComboBox which is present but is invisible. So if I click in the area below Blood Type the list of string will appear.